# Only one JavaScript function loading on page load.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with a few JavaScript functions set to load on document.ready.

However, if I have 4 of these, only the final one seems to load.

Here is the code I have.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var nation = "ireland";
    var irelandMatches = [];
    var matchOrderReversed = false;

    loadDoc();
    showRSS("Irish Times");
    loadWeather();
    loadTwitter();
```

The loadDoc() and loadTwitter() methods load, but weather and showRSS do not. If I comment out loadTwitter(), then the weather loads fine.

If it makes any difference, all of these methods make use of an XMLHttpRequest, each of which is defined within each method, like so.

```
function loadYouTube()
    {
        var html = "";

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        else
        {  // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var ret = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var spl1 = ret.split("~");

                for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    var spl2 = spl1[i].split("*");
                    var current = "<a href='" + spl2[1] + "'><img src='" + spl2[2] + "' width='50' height='50'>" + "<a href='" + spl2[1] + "'>" + spl2[0] + "</a> <br/>";
                    html += current;
                }

                $("#yt").html(html);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getyoutube.php?", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: So are you sure you're not erasing one function html with the other (`$("#yt").html(html);`) or are you using a different element with a different ID in each of the functions?

Comment: It is most likely a run time error. You can simply check that by opening the dev tools in your browser (Firefox and chrome :ctrl + shit + i) and switching to Console. Then, simply reload your page. It is hard or impossible to find the error from the code above because it is impossible to predict what the return of the Ajax response would be.

Comment: Yeah, each function writes to a different DIV.

Comment: Also add `var xmlhttp;` at the top of each of the functions

Comment: @AlonEitan Adding "var xmlhttp;" to the top of each function fixed it. Thanks a million :)

Comment: @user3102785 For what it's worth, that fixed it because you accidentally created a global variable called `xmlhttp`. This means that each of your other functions were overwriting that value so you could only see the result of the last function that used it.

Comment: @MikeC AFAIK you don't have to declare a global variable before, as long as you don't have `"use strict"` - It automatically create this global variable (accessible from `window.xmlhttp`)

Comment: @AlonEitan That's exactly what I said. "you accidentally created a global variable called `xmlhttp`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when you define `xmlhttp` in your `loadYouTube()` example, you are doing so on the global scope due to the lack of `var`. So `loadDoc()` sets `window.xmlhttp`, then `loadWeather()` overwrites it shortly after, followed by `loadTwitter()`.

Try something like this in your loading functions:

```
function loadYouTube()
    {
        var html = "";

        // define xmlhttp in block scope
        var xmlhttp;

        // rest of function...
    }
```